# Android application stops after setText on TextView

Tags: android, textview, settext

I have an android program which sends to another activity after clicking on a button. Mainly, I want to set the text from textview in the new windows so that it corresponds to the selected button. For example, if I click on button Writers, the next new activity should have a textview on which the word Writers appears. Everything works fine, except when I try to setText on the TextView icon for category. I also tried to call this change in the first activity, before launching the second one, it didn't work. 
I also mention that if I comment the line with the setText, the program works just fine.

```
private String          category;
public final static String CATEGORY_MESSAGE = "e.c.project.CATEGORY";
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.actors:
                category = "actors";
                playTheGame(v);
            break;
            case R.id.cartoons:
                category = "cartoons";
                playTheGame(v);
        break;
            case R.id.singers:
                category = "singers";
                playTheGame(v);
            break;
            case R.id.writers:
                category = "writers";
                playTheGame(v);
            break;
        }
    }

    public void playTheGame( View view ){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayGame.class);
        String category = playGameButton.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(CATEGORY_MESSAGE, category);
//      TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.categoryTV);
//      tv.setText(category);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

this is the OnCreate method from the second activity:

```
    private TextView            categoryTV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String category = intent.getStringExtra(GameCategories.CATEGORY_MESSAGE);

    categoryTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.categoryTV);
    categoryTV.setText(category);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);` before `categoryTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.categoryTV);` Otherwise your `TextView` is `null`

```
   private TextView, categoryTV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);  // make this call BEFORE initializing ANY views
       Intent intent = getIntent();
       String category = intent.getStringExtra(GameCategories.CATEGORY_MESSAGE);

       categoryTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.categoryTV);
       categoryTV.setText(category);


        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
         setupActionBar();
    }
```

Your `View`s exist in your `Layout` so if you try to access any of them before inflating your `Layout`, with `setContentView()` or an `inflater`, they will be `null` resulting in a `NPE` when you try to call a method on them such as `setText()`

Comment: I agree, this results in a NPE when calling setText();

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for your prompt reply! I'm pretty new with android and I've been struggling with this for a few hours.

Comment: I now have another issue, the text from the selected button (string precisely in my case) won't appear in the new activity, it only shows up null.

Comment: it does not compile if I simply write CATEGORY_MESSAGE (as it does not know where to take the variable from). I tried to write the exact same key (the value of CATEGORY_MESSAGE), "e.c.project.CATEGORY" and it still does not work. Also, when I try to run the program using String category = playGameButton.getText().toString(); it stops, so I modified it to intent.putExtra(CATEGORY_MESSAGE, category);, where category is the global string.

Comment: If I remove static it says "cannot make a static reference to a non-static element".

Comment: I don't understand where you are trying to use `CATEGORY_MESSAGE` If it is in the `Intent` then you just need to make sure whatever you use for the `key` in `intent.putExtra("key", value")` you use that `key` to retrieve the value in `getIntent().getStringExtra("key")`

Comment: I do that. In activity1 I write   intent.putExtra(CATEGORY_MESSAGE, category); and in activity2 I write Intent intent = getIntent();
  String category = intent.getStringExtra(GameCategories.CATEGORY_MESSAGE); Sorry if I fail in explaining things exactly.

Comment: That's ok, I just don't understand where you are getting the error now.

Comment: When I run the application, when I get to activity two, the text on textview is not "cartoons" or "actors" or "singers", as it should be, it is "null" here is a photo to depict it better: http://oi43.tinypic.com/30rwd9f.jpg

Comment: First, have you verified with breakpoints that `category` has a value when you call `intent.putExtra(CATEGORY_MESSAGE);`? Second, did you remove the `static` identifier from the declaration of `CATEGORY_MESSAGE` and changed when you get the value to `String category = intent.getStringExtra(CATEGORY_MESSAGE);`?

Comment: You're right. The problem is on string category. It seems it does not have a value when I call the intent.putExtra (although, I did assigned it just before calling the function, on switch case). Thanks a lot for bearing with me!

Comment: You give it a value in `onClick` then you create a new variable with the same name right before you put the string using the text of the `Button`. Not sure exactly what you're doing there but that is where your problem lies. Investigate that area